# What is the "value" of an array variable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

I have this example in a book:

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 10000 /* size of available space */

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; /* storage for alloc */
static char *allocp = allocbuf; /* next free position */

char *alloc(int n) /* return pointer to n characters */
{
    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) { /* it fits */
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n; /* old p */
    } else /* not enough room */
      return 0;
}

void afree(char *p) /* free storage pointed to by p */
{
     if (p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)
         allocp = p;
}
```

I need to know what `allocbuf` represents (its value) so it is used in:

```
if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n)
```

Comment: It will be converted to a pointer to the first element of the array in the expression.

Comment: in C, referencing an array name results in the address of the first byte of the array.

Comment: in C, be careful about performing math on pointers, This is not a problem if the pointers are to the same array, (as yours are) but the compiler will choke on any pointers that are not to the same array.

Comment: Hi @John, you have asked 6 questions so far but accepted no answer yet. Please reward the people who have helped you and accept answers to your questions (which also helps others who have similar problems). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the array decays into the pointer to its storage location. In other words: the pointer to its first element.

You can use `allocbuf` (or better yet: `&allocbuf[0]` which better transports the meaning of "pointer to the first element") to get the pointer to the first element, and `allocp` is intended to point to the next free element. So `allocp - allocbuf` will give you the number of elements "used".

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1/p3, (*emphasis mine*)

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. [...]

So, in your code, `allocbuf`, which is an array type, when used as

```
if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) {
```

will decay to the pointer to the first element of the array.